# SSH client not showing prompt after successful login

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm having problems with my SSH client on Ubuntu 10.10.

When I switch on my computer and open a Terminal and execute the command **ssh user@host**, it gives me a password prompt after which I enter the right password, I then get a prompt to execute my commands on the remote computer.

Now the problem is, after a little while (probably around 10 minutes), the terminal window stops accepting commands (No matter what I type, nothing shows). Once this happens, I close the Terminal window and try to start all over again by opening another Terminal window. But this time around, after entering the right password, I don't get a welcome message or prompt. The cursor just keeps blinking on a new line.

I ran the ssh command with **-v** parameter and the message I get after a successful login is:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.utf8
```

Still the cursor keeps blinking on a new line without a prompt.

However, Putty SSH client works perfectly on the same machine.

Thank you very much for your time. Your help would be greating appreciated.

Comment: Already tried with multiple `-v -v -v`?

Comment: Same question posted on serverfault. see answer here: http://serverfault.com/a/582490/212983

Answer (score 1):

Try this command at the server side of SSH in order to verify:

**netstat --route**

I had the same problem because IT changed the Internet provider and didn't update a gateway in a route.

Answer (score 0):

Check for network / connectivity issues.

```
telnet host 22
```

(presuming you run your SSH on port 22)

Try connecting to other SSH hosts.